# Cannot pass NSString to a NSURL URLWithString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Try to pass my `NSString` to a `URLWithString` but no url appear:

```
//here i get my url from my API and replacing tags
NSString *queryContent = [[[(webLinks)[@"content"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"]
                                                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<p>" withString:@""]
                                                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</p>" withString:@""];
//here i get the full url 
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:queryContent];
```

Adding a NSLogs:

```
 NSLog(@"query:%@", queryContent);
 NSLog(@"website:%@", url);
```

and the result is this:

```
query:http://mywebsite.com
website:(null)
```

Whats wrong?

thanks

Comment: can you please mention [[(webLinks)[@"content"] contain ?

Comment: is a parsing from a tableView an containg a web link like <p>http://mywebsite</p>

Comment: Are you sure `queryContent` has no spaces at the end?

Comment: yes i try to add repalce all space with nothing

Comment: Remove html tag first and then try
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone

Comment: I doubt its a problem for encoding. Please check this link [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443040/how-to-url-encode-a-nsstring)

Comment: thx i try to remove tags with this method  (stackoverflow.com/questions/15443040/…) but still continue same problem, remove correctly the tags, but website Log is (null)

Comment: Can u print (webLinks)[@"content"]  at ur question..

Comment: adding to my answer what i get from a website

Comment: same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170656/strange-issue-with-nsurl-with-xocode6-1

Answer (score 1):

**//SOLVED//**

here the correct code if any of you use my same system JSON API for WordPress:

```
NSRange r;
NSString *queryUrl = [(webLinks)[@"content"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
NSString *website = queryUrl;
while ((r = [website rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    website = [website stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:website];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```